# How to add combobox in datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I want to add combobox column in datagridview in c# by programatically. How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: There is a class called DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, create an object of its type set the properties you need and add it to your DataGridView via yourGridView.Columns.Add(yourComboBox);

Comment: thanks @MeAndSomeRandoms, now i am avialable to add combobox to dgv. thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one simple approach, which allows to programatically add `ComboBox` in `DataGridView`

```
var combocolumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combocolumn.Name = "Numbers"; // Column name
combocolumn.DataSource = new int[] { "1", "2" }; // Your Data source

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combocolumn);
```